# Installation Shield for JavaEE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, installshield, webdeploy

I want to install/implement our product in a client machine, for that i have manual procedure, but i want to automate this process, i.e **i want to prepare a installation shield** for this process.

I will keep all the required files in one place for example:

1. war files
2. Data base dump files.
3. Required db scripts

When i click on the .exe (if we created installation shield, we will get .exe) it has to ask the location about the above files, And do the installation process.i can do this by using swing , but i am searching for some readily available tools (open source) which contains more features.

Expected things to be done by the installation shield:
1)Importing the dump files into already created DB user.
2)placing the above wars in to JBoss deployment folder / deployment procedure.
3)Creating the shortcuts to start & stop the JBoss server in desktop.

Please help me, from where i can get such tool which can do the above or similar activities.

Answer (score 0):

Try NSIS Script. Its easy to use and has good support forums available. http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

I would look into. IzPack http://izpack.org/

We do similair tasks setting up and deploying both wars and ears using it.